# Is it possible to put a bullet in a v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

The table

[image]

**The data that is in the Database** it is only separated by commas.

```
Hepatitis A IgM Antibody (Anti-HAV IgM),
Hepatitis A Total Antibody (Anti-HAV Total),
Hepatitis B Core Antibody (Anti HBc Total),
Hepatitis B Core IgM Antibody (Anti-HBc IgM),
Hepatitis B Envelop Antibody (Anti-HBe),
Hepatitis B Envelop Antigen (HBeAg),
Hepatitis B Surface Antibody (Anti-HBs),
Hepatitis B Surface Antigen,
Hepatitis C Antibody (Anti-HCV),
Qualitative (HBsAg)
```

Frontend structure.

[image]

**The output that I needed**
[image]

My code:

```
   <q-list
                  v-for="specificPackage in specificPackages"
                  v-bind:key="specificPackage.id"
                  class="q-pa-md"
                  bordered
                >
                <q-card-section horizontal>
                  <q-card-section class="q-pt-xs">
                    <div class="text-h6 q-pt-md text-black" caption>
                      LABORATORY TESTS:
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-subtitle1 q-pt-md packageitem">
                      {{ specificPackage.packageitem }}
                    </div>
                  </q-card-section>
                </q-card-section>
              </q-card>
              <q-separator />
            </q-list>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can split "specificPackage.packageitem" on the bases of comma and loop it with <li>

Comment: @KamranKhalid how do you that in a specific column of the table?

Comment: @Grizzle Bear i this case you need to use v-if or it will be better please share a complete row for better understanding

Comment: @KamranKhalid I have edited and uploaded the table for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split string into array and then loop the array

```
<q-list
                  v-for="specificPackage in specificPackages"
                  v-bind:key="specificPackage.id"
                  class="q-pa-md"
                  bordered
                >
                <q-card-section horizontal>
                  <q-card-section class="q-pt-xs">
                    <div class="text-h6 q-pt-md text-black" caption>
                      LABORATORY TESTS:
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-subtitle1 q-pt-md packageitem">
                      <li v-for="(packageitem, i) in specificPackage.packageitem.split(',')" :key="i">
        {{packageitem}}
    /li>
                    </div>
                  </q-card-section>
                </q-card-section>
              </q-card>
              <q-separator />
            </q-list>
```

Comment: How do you that if you have displayed it like this?   <li>{{ specificPackage.packageitem }}</li> that li tag only has the bullet of the name Hepatitis A IgM Antibody (Anti-HAV IgM) while the rest has none

Comment: Before displaying am splitting string into array